# Approximate $f(x,y)$ by $g_1(x)h_1(y)+\dots+g_n(x)h_n(y)$ for compact topological spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, approximation-theory

This problem is from my final exam:

Let $C(X)_\Bbb R$ denote the set of all $\Bbb R$-valued continuous functions on $X$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact *topological* spaces. Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ and and any $f\in C(X\times Y)_\Bbb R$ there exists $g_1,\dots,g_n\in C(X)_\Bbb R$ and $h_1,\dots,h_n\in C(Y)_\Bbb R$ (for some $n\in\Bbb N$) such that
$$
\left|f(x,y)-\sum_{k=1}^ng_k(x)h_k(y)\right|<\epsilon\text{ for all }(x, y)\in X\times Y\text{.}
$$

---

Multiple weaker versions have been asked on this site, but seems like they cannot be generalized trivially to this one. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/479505/79512) assumes $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134247/prove-that-if-f-in-cx-times-y-then-there-exists-functions) assumes $X$ and $Y$ are metrizable. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147855/function-in-mathcalcx-times-y-can-be-approximated-by-sum-of-finite-numb) doesn't but its accepted answer does. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147855/function-in-mathcalcx-times-y-can-be-approximated-by-sum-of-finite-numb) is even weaker, assuming $X=Y=[0,1]$.

It still looks like an application of Stone-Weierstrass theorem. The problem is $\sum gh$ does not necessarily seperate points of $X\times Y$. For example, when $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets equipped with trivial topology, the only continuous functions are constant functions.

Comment: See if these answers may be useful http://mathoverflow.net/a/166250/45979, http://mathoverflow.net/a/255887/45979